# CMake warnings disappear when using other CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE

Tags: build, cmake, warnings

I'm using cmake version 3.5.1.
If cmake is executed on a project with `-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release` as argument warnings about CMake Warning (dev) Policy CMP0043 for the CMakeLists.txt are shown.

But when I use `-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug` (and nothing else changed) curiously the warnings are not longer shown, even when adding `-Wdev -Wdeprecated`.

Why are the warnings disappearing when using a other build type and how do I get them back?

Comment: Policy [CMP0043](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/policy/CMP0043.html) is about using target's property `COMPILE_DEFINITIONS_<Config>`. According to description, CMake should warns if someone uses these properties. Looks like in case of *single-configuration* generators CMake checks only properties for active configuration. That is, if someone sets `COMPILE_DEFINITIONS_RELEASE` property, CMake warns about it in "Release" build but completely ignores it in "Debug" build.